# Clarification on SP:CacheHit Event in SQL Profiler

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, caching, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4.1

I would like to clear something up in my understanding on the "SP:CacheHit" event in SQL Profiler.

Is it safe to assume that whenever a "SP:CacheHit" event is shown against an execution of a stored procedure that no hit is being made to the database? The reason I ask is because I currently have a query (using Entity Framework/LINQ) that selects one random record out of 4000 rows in a table.

Has SQL Server truly cached 4000 records of data from my table, so any subsequent queries will not hit the database?

The series of events are as follows:

1. RPC:Starting
2. SP:CacheHit
3. SP:StmtStarting
4. SP:StmtCompleted  --> This is where I see the number of reads and row counts
5. RPC:Completed     --> This is where I see the number of reads and row counts

I found this useful [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/09/13/ef-caching-with-jarek-kowalski-s-provider.aspx) that somewhat clarified my understanding, but confirmation from one of my fellow experts would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just means that the SP itself was found in the execution plan cache.  This means that the SP doesn't need to be re-compiled.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173892(v=sql.80).aspx

Line 3 onward, in your example, shows that the database is itself being interrogated to complete the query.

Comment: And when the plan is not found, you'd see `SP:Recompile`.  +1